# How to truncate text?

Tags: angular

I want to crop the text. For this I use this [module](https://github.com/yellowspot/ng2-truncate). But because I use `innerHTML` to truncate the text does not work.

How else can you trim the text?

```
<div [innerHTML]="notebook.description">
  <p>{{ notebook.description |  truncate : 20 }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If it's only text that you want to truncate, you probably don't need a whole library for that. You first need to study JavaScript.

Comment: You can do it in CSS, but you'll also need to restrict it to a single line of text

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pure CSS:

```css
div.b {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 20ch;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h2>text-overflow: ellipsis:</h2>
  <div class="b">Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world!</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'd recommend using the `ch` unit instead of `px`. That way, it can be set to `20ch`, i.e. 20 characters as per the truncate OP was using before